# Running tryton client in ubuntu

Tags: tryton

Please help me to resolve this issue about the running of `tryton client`.

There is the stack trace of my bug when I run `tryton client` in `ubuntu`:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/tryton", line 45, in <module>
    from tryton import client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tryton/client.py", line 24, in <module>
    import tryton.common as common
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tryton/common/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from common import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tryton/common/common.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tryton.config import CONFIG
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tryton/config.py", line 188, in <module>
    os.path.join(PIXMAPS_DIR, 'tryton-icon.png').encode('utf-8'))
glib.GError: Failed to open file '/usr/share/pixmaps/tryton/tryton-icon.png': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Where do you have that file? tryton-icon.png. Run 'locate tryton-icon.png'

Comment: Thank you for your response, tryton-icon.png is located in the following path: root/tryton-3.4.3/share/pixmaps/tryton.  Please I need your help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have been hit by https://bugs.tryton.org/issue4102 which is solved for the latest versions You have three solutions:

1. (simple): Create a simlink from /usr/share/pixmaps/tryton to root/tryton-3.4.3/share/pixmaps/tryton so the icons will be read correctly. Open a terminal and execute:

> ```
> cd /usr/shar/pixmaps/ 
> ln -s /root/tryton-3.4.3/share/pixmaps/tryton
> ```

2. (simple). Use the latest stable (3.6) series (server must also be updated) from https://launchpad.net/~rayanayar/+archive/ubuntu/tryton-3.6
3. (advanced). Download the patch in the linked issue and apply it manually to your tryton client

Comment: Hello pokoli, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: I choose the second solution but it's not working for me. The stack trace show me many bugs related to the code source of tryton!!! . In this list i show you the stack trace detail: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/root/tryton-3.6.0/tryton/gui/main.py:69: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance self.window = gtk.Window()